# Controller only saving last element in array

Tags: php, laravel

Have asked this question before but it wasn't answered.So am asking again.I have a table subjects with columns:

```
id->primary key,auto-increment;
class_id->foreign key->refrences id on classes table;
subject;
and a users table:
id->primary key,auto-increment;
username;
password;
and a classes table:
id->primary,autoincrement;
class;
term;
and a pivot table student_user: 
id->primary;
user_id->refrences id on users table;
subject_id->refrences id on subject table;
class_id->foreign,refrences id on classes table;
```

And i have my model to define there relationship thus

```
//User Model 
//User.php



public function subjects()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Subject');
    }

    public function myclass()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('SchoolClass');
    }

//Class Model
//SchoolClass.php



 public function subjects()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('Subject','class_id');
    }

//Subject Model
//Subject.php
public function term()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('SchoolClass');
    }

    public function student()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
```

Now here comes the problem.When ever i try to insert data into the pivot table subject_user,only the the last data in the array of values that i want to insert gets saved into the database.I dont know if its the foreign constraint keys that's only updating the row instead of inserting a new one when looping through data.I cant figure out what is wrong.And below is my controller to see how my data is been inserted.Am not very conversant with relationships in laravel

```
//Save Registered Courses


public function post_proceed_registration()
        {
            $PageTitle = 'Register Subjects';
            $id        = Auth::user()->id;
            $User      = User::find($id);
            $class_id  = $User->profile->class_id;
            $subjects  = Input::get('subjects');
            $registration = RegistrationCheck::where('class_id',$class_id)->where('user_id',$id)->pluck('status');

            if(count(Input::get('students')) != 0)
            {
                if($registration == 'true')
                {
                PivotSubject::where('user_id',$id)->where('class_id',$class_id)->delete();

                foreach($subjects as $sub_id)
                    {
                        $subject = new PivotSubject;

                        $subject->user_id = $id;
                        $subject->subject_id = $sub_id;
                        $subject->class_id   = $class_id;

                        $subject->save();
                    }

                RegistrationCheck::where('class_id',$class_id)->where('user_id',$id)->update(['status'=>'false']);

                return Response::Json('Success: Subject/Courses Registered');
                }
            return Response::Json('Error: You already registered for this Term/Semester.Please Contact ICT for help');
            }
            return Response::Json('Error:You did not choose any course to register');
        }
```

Am stucked here.Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Please someone look this up for me

Comment: What happens if you create and save a few subjects outside the loop (with sample data)? are they getting saved normally?

Comment: yes, they are getting saved normally

Comment: Hmm. Can you make sure the loop really "works"? For example by echoing something out every time?

Comment: sometimes it saves all data,most times the last data

Comment: $check = [];

foreach($Class_Subjects as $data)
{
   $check[]=Subject::create(array('class_id' => Input::get('class_id'),'subject' => $data,'subject_slug' => Str::Slug($data)));
}
return $check; return me an object instance of what am trying to save:

Comment: [
{
"class_id": "8",
"subject": "one",
"subject_slug": "one",
"updated_at": "2014-11-20 12:52:51",
"created_at": "2014-11-20 12:52:51",
"id": 26
},
{
"class_id": "8",
"subject": "two",
"subject_slug": "two",
"updated_at": "2014-11-20 12:52:51",
"created_at": "2014-11-20 12:52:51",
"id": 27
},
{
"class_id": "8",
"subject": "three",
"subject_slug": "three",
"updated_at": "2014-11-20 12:52:51",
"created_at": "2014-11-20 12:52:51",
"id": 28
}
]

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about what your db schema looks like. But based on what you have described, I highly doubt this code:

```
                $subject = new Subject;

```
            $subject->class_id      = $Class_id;
            $subject->subject       = ucfirst($data);
            $subject->subject_slug  = Str::Slug(ucfirst($data));

            $subject->save();
```

```

1. Does your subject only include three columns, namely class_id, subject and subject_slug?
2. Have you set class_id as your primary key?

Because all subjects have the same class_id, if class_id is set to be primary, probably you are always updating the same database entry.

To further investigate, set input of $Class_Subjects to length of 1 or simply only loop once to get the first subject info. Insert it into database and see if the entry in database now changes.

A sample code may look like this:

```
                $subject = new Subject;

```
            $subject->class_id      = $Class_id;
            $subject->subject       = ucfirst($data);
            $subject->subject_slug  = Str::Slug(ucfirst($data));

            $subject->save();
            break;
```

```
Please let me know more results.

Comment: #ray please check my code update if it makes u understand my plight better

Comment: have u checked it out